# Chrome setting or extension to support theme-color on desktop

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, themes

I really like the way on mobile chrome tab bar re-colours to match the website's theme colour. Recently safari added support for this too - but then took away the ability to have it at the same time as keeping a separate address bar. I can't deal with having my address bar integrated into the tabs line, so I'm turning back to chrome.

Does anyone know of a setting or extension that will re-theme chrome based on the active website's theme colour? (No, I don't want to use Vivaldi haha). It seems like a really simple thing to do, yet a few google searches have got me nowhere except a single reddit post from five years ago, with only two comments and no answer in sight. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Looking at the Chrome Extension API, the Chrome Web Store and the settings in Chrome, I don't see any options to recolor tabs. There are ways to change favicons and so maybe that could be leveraged to make a colored swatch that match the website's background color. But it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yet you can recolour Chrome with a custom static theme - there's no way to create an extension that dynamically sets the theme is there?

Comment: That's my understanding--themes cannot contain scripts, so themes & extensions are separate universes. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/themes/